# How to get Excel cell value in C++

Tags: c++, excel, automation, cell

If someone knows how to go from Excel::Window pointer to real value in opened Excel cell, please let me know. 
Here is the task conditions:
- Excel is currently running in one single window with one workbook on one sheet
- some cells have data (to simplify let's say only one cell[1,1] has data, which is "a")
The question is how to find out that only one cell has data, and cell is [1,1] and the data is "a".
To start with here is a code snippet:

```
int main( int argc, CHAR* argv[])
{
   CoInitialize( NULL );
   HWND excelWindow = FindWindow(L"XLMAIN", NULL);
   EnumChildWindows(excelWindow, (WNDENUMPROC) EnumChildProc, (LPARAM)1);
   return 0;
}
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM)
{
   WCHAR szClassName[64];
   if(GetClassNameW(hwnd, szClassName, 64))
   {
      if(_wcsicmp(szClassName, L"EXCEL7") == 0)
      {
         Excel::Window* pWindow = NULL;
         HRESULT hr = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd, OBJID_NATIVEOM, __uuidof(Excel::Window), (void**)&pWindow);
         if(hr == S_OK)
         {
            // Here we need to answer the question using pWindow                
            pWindow->Release();
         }
         return false;     
      }     
   }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is code finally used:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <oleacc.h>
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\MSO.DLL" no_implementation rename("RGB", "ExclRGB") rename("DocumentProperties", "ExclDocumentProperties") rename("SearchPath", "ExclSearchPath")
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB" no_implementation
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE" rename("DialogBox", "ExclDialogBox") rename("RGB", "ExclRGB") rename("CopyFile", "ExclCopyFile") rename("ReplaceText", "ExclReplaceText")
#include <string>
using std::string;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM)
{
    WCHAR szClassName[64];
    if(GetClassNameW(hwnd, szClassName, 64))
    {
        if(_wcsicmp(szClassName, L"EXCEL7") == 0)
        {
            //Get AccessibleObject
            Excel::Window* pWindow = NULL;
            IDispatch* pXlSheet = NULL;
            HRESULT hr = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd, OBJID_NATIVEOM, __uuidof(Excel::Window), (void**)&pWindow);
            if(hr == S_OK)
            {               
                try {
                    VARIANT result;
                    VariantInit(&result);
                    AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pWindow, L"ActiveSheet", 0);
                    pXlSheet = result.pdispVal;
                    _variant_t sheetName;
                    VariantInit(&sheetName);
                    if ((pXlSheet != NULL) && (pXlSheet != (IDispatch*)0xCCCCCCCC))
                    AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &sheetName, pXlSheet, L"Name", 0); 

                    // get cell which you need
                    string location = "C5"; 
                    location += ":" + location; // cell is a range with the same start/end cells
                    OLECHAR *sOleText=new OLECHAR[location.length()+1];
                    mbstowcs(sOleText,location.c_str(),location.length()+1);

                    IDispatch *pXlRange; // Get Range from Sheet
                    VARIANT parm;
                    parm.vt = VT_BSTR;
                    parm.bstrVal = ::SysAllocString(sOleText); 
                    VARIANT result;
                    VariantInit(&result);
                    AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pXlSheet, L"Range", 1, parm);
                    VariantClear(&parm);
                    pXlRange = result.pdispVal;
                    Excel::RangePtr cell = pXlRange;
                    Excel::CharactersPtr ptr = cell->Characters;
                    _bstr_t text = ptr->Text; // here is needed text
                } catch (...) { }
            }
            return false;     // Stops enumerating through children
        }       
    }
    return true;
}

void main( int argc, CHAR* argv[])
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    HWND excelWindow = FindWindow(L"XLMAIN", NULL);
    EnumChildWindows(excelWindow, (WNDENUMPROC) EnumChildProc, (LPARAM)1);
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

The AutoWrap() function has been taken from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216686/en-us?fr=1, while the initial sample from http://www.northatlantawebdesign.com/index.php/2009/07/15/access-microsoft-excel-2007-com-api-through-microsoft-active-accessibility/
Thanks to all who helped.

Comment: Why compare pXlSheet to 0xCCCCCCCC)? You have initialized pXlSheet.

Answer (score 0):

Daniil,

I believe you are using the Excel COM to access it. I've never done this using C++, but I guess it shouldn't be much different than C#. Your toughest task should be importing the necessary libraries to do so. But I believe you have done that already.

You should use something like this:

```
int full_cells = 0;
Excel::_Worksheet worksheet = pWindow->ActiveSheet;
for(int j = 1; j < worksheet.Columns.Count; j++)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < worksheet.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if(worksheet.Cells[i][j].Value != "")
        {
            full_cells++;
            cout << worksheet.Cells[i][j].Value;
        }
     }
}
```

Please note I haven't tested this code. I'm just showing you what it is supposed to look like. You should read the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms262200.aspx and use it appropriately.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello, Theo. Thanks for code snippet. Unfortunately it illustrates the main idea only, which is clear for me from the very beginning. If you will try to insert this snippet into my code you will get a lot of code errors, like incompatible types. It is not so obvious like in C# how to deal with all this code. Also documentation is useful as a reference book, but what I need is the instruction. Thus the question is still opened.