# Obtaining the Excel.Application IDispatch* within a dll that's been loaded into Excel

Tags: c++, dll, com, xll

Does anyone know how to get hold of the `Excel.Application` `IDispatch*` pointer associated with an excel process into which an `dll` has been loaded?

A key thing here is that the process is `excel.exe`, and the pointer I need *must* belong to that process. Using the Running Object Table will not fly since Excel only registers its first instance with that.

I'm hoping there is some low-level COM trickery, but I'm not an expert in that field.

Comment: Have you [seen this MSKB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190985)?

Comment: That seems to use the Running Object Table.

Comment: Indeed it does: so will not be of any use I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure on first reading (otherwise I would have posted as an answer) - I'm intrigued about why you need to do this though, maybe there's another way ... can you expand your question?

Comment: @Roger Rowland, the reason for requirement is pretty intricate: it boils down to some financial engineering code that can attach itself to an excel process (as well as other systems). If attached to excel, then some interface components can bind to that excel for result output. For other reasons, I can't get Excel to pass the pointer on startup. That's why I need to get the application pointer. Using the xll interface will not work due to other requirements that I ought not detail here. Hope this helps a little; if a bit vague.

Comment: Do you have requirement for Excel version, Os Version, bitness, and so on...?

Comment: I'd be happy with anything on or after Excel12, WindowsXP, and 32 or 64 bit: I'll port the solution if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED II** Code is under the [WTFPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTFPL#Version_2) license version 2.

**EDITED**: Add PID parameter to allow filtering when several Excel processes are currently running, as per comment suggestion from @EricBrown.

I managed to get a working `IDispatch*` to an Excel "Application" object without using the ROT. The trick is to use MSAA. My code works as a stand alone console application, but I think that if the code is executed in an Excel process, via DLL Injection, it MAY works fine. You may have to be in a dedicated thread. Let me know if you want me to push the expriment to the DLL injection level.

Tested OK on Window7 64b, with a UNICODE builds (32 bits and 64 bits).
Excel version 2010 64 bits (version "14")

I get the IDispatch via the "application" property from an "Worksheet" object. Consequence: there must be an opened worksheet. In order to find the good MSSA Window, I need the class name of the Top Level Excel Frame Window. In Excel 2010, it's "XLMAIN". The class name for worksheets is "EXCEL7" and that seems to be a "standard".

I was not able to directly get a working `IDispatch*` from the main Excel Window, but have not tried very hard. That may involve #import with a automation DLL from Excel, in order to QueryInterface the IDispatch that MSAA gives for the main Window (that IDispatch is NOT for an Application object)

```
#include <atlbase.h>

#pragma comment( lib, "Oleacc.lib" )

HRESULT GetExcelAppDispatch( CComPtr<IDispatch> & spIDispatchExcelApp, DWORD dwExcelPID ) {

   struct ew {
      struct ep {
         _TCHAR* pszClassName;
         DWORD dwPID;
         HWND hWnd;
      };
      static BOOL CALLBACK ewp( HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam ) {
         TCHAR szClassName[ 64 ];
         if ( GetClassName( hWnd, szClassName, 64 ) ) {
            ep* pep = reinterpret_cast<ep*>( lParam );
            if ( _tcscmp( szClassName, pep->pszClassName ) == 0 ) {
               if ( pep->dwPID == 0 ) {
                  pep->hWnd = hWnd;
                  return FALSE;
               } else {
                  DWORD dwPID;
                  if ( GetWindowThreadProcessId( hWnd, &dwPID ) ) {
                     if ( dwPID == pep->dwPID ) {
                        pep->hWnd = hWnd;
                        return FALSE;
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
         return TRUE;
      }
   };

   ew::ep ep;

   ep.pszClassName = _TEXT( "XLMAIN" );
   ep.dwPID = dwExcelPID;
   ep.hWnd = NULL;
   EnumWindows( ew::ewp, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>( &ep ) );
   HWND hWndExcel = ep.hWnd;
   if ( ep.hWnd == NULL ) {
      printf( "Can't Find Main Excel Window with EnumWindows\n" );
      return -1;
   }

   ep.pszClassName = _TEXT( "EXCEL7" );
   ep.dwPID = 0;
   ep.hWnd = NULL;
   EnumChildWindows( hWndExcel, ew::ewp, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>( &ep ) );
   HWND hWndWorkSheet = ep.hWnd;
   if ( hWndWorkSheet == NULL ) {
      printf( "Can't Find a WorkSheet with EnumChildWindows\n" );
      return -1;
   }

   CComPtr<IDispatch> spIDispatchWorkSheet;
   HRESULT hr = AccessibleObjectFromWindow( hWndWorkSheet, OBJID_NATIVEOM, IID_IDispatch,
                                            reinterpret_cast<void**>( &spIDispatchWorkSheet ) );
   if ( FAILED( hr ) || ( spIDispatchWorkSheet == 0 ) ) {
      printf( "AccessibleObjectFromWindow Failed\n" );
      return hr;
   }
   CComVariant vExcelApp;
   hr = spIDispatchWorkSheet.GetPropertyByName( CComBSTR( "Application" ), &vExcelApp );
   if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) && ( vExcelApp.vt == VT_DISPATCH ) ) {
      spIDispatchExcelApp = vExcelApp.pdispVal;
      return S_OK;
   }
   return hr;

}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

   DWORD dwExcelPID = 0;
   if ( argc > 1 ) dwExcelPID = _ttol( argv[ 1 ] );

   HRESULT hr = CoInitialize( NULL );
   bool bCoUnInitializeTodo = false;
   if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
      bCoUnInitializeTodo = true;
      CComPtr<IDispatch> spDispatchExcelApp;
      hr = GetExcelAppDispatch( spDispatchExcelApp, dwExcelPID );
      if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) && spDispatchExcelApp ) {
         CComVariant vExcelVer;
         hr = spDispatchExcelApp.GetPropertyByName( CComBSTR( "Version" ), &vExcelVer );
         if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) && ( vExcelVer.vt == VT_BSTR ) ) {
            wprintf( L"Excel Version is %s\n", vExcelVer.bstrVal );
         }
      }
   }
   if ( bCoUnInitializeTodo ) CoUninitialize();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a very good implementation, but the code to locate the main window is wrong; you should check the process ID of the main window, rather than just the first one.

Comment: @EricBrown Thanks. But I don't understand what is the check I should have done. Do you mean "verifying that it is an 'Excel.exe' process?

Comment: given that this needs to be in an XLL and find the `XLMAIN` window for *that particular process*, instead of using `FindWindow`, it should use `EnumWindows` and check for class == `"XLMAIN"` and then use `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to check for the process ID.

Comment: This has legs. Thank you for taking the time. +1, accept and bounty. I will not copy the code verbatim as it's going into commercial software but will be using your AccessibleObjectFromWindow technique.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks! Updated with license :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find out how to do this by reviewing the code in [ExcelDNA](https://exceldna.codeplex.com/). This project contains code that hooks back into Excel from the extension library. The code is likely to be more elaborate that you need, but will implement the reference you require.

Comment: Nice idea but I don't want the overhead of .NET framework runtime.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it: (acknowledge @manuell). `dispatch_wrapper` is a class, here is the constructor to set `m_disp_application`:

```
dispatch_wrapper(void)
{
    DWORD target_process_id = ::GetProcessId(::GetCurrentProcess());

    if (getProcessName() == "excel.exe"){
        HWND hwnd = ::FindWindowEx(0, 0, "XLMAIN", NULL);
        while (hwnd){
            DWORD process_id;
            ::GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &process_id);
            if (process_id == target_process_id){
                HWND hwnd_desk = ::FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0, "XLDESK", NULL);
                HWND hwnd_7 = ::FindWindowEx(hwnd_desk, 0, "EXCEL7", NULL);
                IDispatch* p = nullptr;
                if (SUCCEEDED(::AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd_7, OBJID_NATIVEOM, IID_IDispatch, (void**)&p))){
                    LPOLESTR name[1] = {L"Application"};
                    DISPID dispid;
                    if (SUCCEEDED(p->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, name, 1U, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &dispid))){
                        CComVariant v;
                        DISPPARAMS dp;
                        ::memset(&dp, NULL, sizeof(DISPPARAMS));
                        EXCEPINFO ei;
                        ::memset(&ei, NULL, sizeof(EXCEPINFO));
                        if (SUCCEEDED(p->Invoke(dispid, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &dp, &v, &ei, NULL))){
                            if (v.vt == VT_DISPATCH){
                                m_disp_application = v.pdispVal;
                                m_disp_application->AddRef();
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            hwnd = ::FindWindowEx(0, hwnd, "XLMAIN", NULL);
        }
    }
    m_disp_application = nullptr;
}
```

`getProcessName()` returns lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Because Office applications register their documents in the ROT, you can attach to instances beside the first one (which is already in the ROT) by [getting IDispatch for documents in the ROT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190985/en-us), then you can use document.Application.hwnd (this is VBA, you need to [translate to IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames and IDispatch::Invoke with DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619530/how-to-get-excel-cell-value-in-c)) to get the window handles of all Excel instances.

Now you have a mapping between IDispatch and Windows handles of all Excel instances, it is time to find your own Excel instance. You can call GetWindowThreadProcessId on the window handles to get the process ids, then compare to your own process id returned by GetCurrentProcessId to see which excel window belongs to your current process, and look up in the HWND to IDispatch mapping to find your current Excel application's IDispatch interface.

Comment: Care to explain the downvoting?